# Subtracting columns in a mutlilevel pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivot table that for each top level column, I want to subtract the two columns one level below and add the result as a third column.

```
stats = { 
    'YEAR' : [2020, 2020,   2020,   2020,   2022,   2022,   2022,   2022], 
    'PLAYER' : ['BILL','BOB',   'BILL','BOB','BILL','BOB','BILL','BOB'],
    'STAT' : ['SINGLES', 'SINGLES', 'HOME RUNS', 'HOME RUNS','SINGLES', 'SINGLES', 'HOME RUNS', 'HOME RUNS'],
    'COUNT' :  [101,    135,    24, 42, 144,    135,    28, 34]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(stats) 

df_piv = df.pivot_table(values = 'COUNT', columns=['PLAYER','YEAR'], index='STAT')
```

Gives me

```
| PLAYER    | BILL |      | BOB  |      |
| YEAR      | 2020 | 2022 | 2020 | 2022 |
| STAT      |      |      |      |      |
|-----------|------|------|------|------|
| HOME RUNS |   24 |   28 |   42 |   34 |
| SINGLES   |  101 |  144 |  135 |  135 |
```

I attempted

```
df_delta = df_piv.groupby(level='PLAYER', axis=1).diff()
```

But that gives me

```
| PLAYER    | BILL |      | BOB  |      |
| YEAR      | 2020 | 2022 | 2020 | 2022 |
| STAT      |      |      |      |      |
|-----------|------|------|------|------|
| HOME RUNS |  NaN |    4 |  NaN |   -8 |
| SINGLES   |  NaN |   43 |  NaN |    0 |
```

What I am looking for is something like

```
| PLAYER    | BILL |      |       | BOB  |      |       |
| YEAR      | 2020 | 2022 | DELTA | 2020 | 2022 | DELTA |
| STAT      |      |      |       |      |      |       |
|-----------|------|------|-------|------|------|-------|
| HOME RUNS |   24 |   28 |     4 |   42 |   34 |    -8 |
| SINGLES   |  101 |  144 |    43 |  135 |  135 |     0 |
```

Comment: you need to change to `diff(-1)` to `diff(+1)` as you need the difference other way, and also `{"large": "diff"}` to `{2022: "DELTA"}` in the linked answer.